# How can I compare the list of installed packages in two virtualenvs

Tags: python, virtualenv

Something like this has been discussed for conda

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3781

and has been slapped together here

https://gist.github.com/ChrisBarker-NOAA/00106a2af2029259ba7496f865c39086

To reduce the cognitive load of remembering what packages are in which environments, I would like something like

'virtualenv-diff env1 env2'

Does this exist?

Comment: if you are using pip, while running your virtual env. you can ‘$pip list’ for each and then compare

Comment: not useful. I'm trying to reduce cognitive load and  not have to compare lists manually. For example, a table with packages listed on the left column and environment labels across the top is what I have in mind. The 'cell' of each table could have the version number of the package if it is present in the environment or be left blank if not.